# Account verification error

Tags: users, control-panel

I have created a new account and attempted to verify the account by clicking the activation link in the verification email.  On doing so I get the following error.

```
Bad Request
Param “id” doesn’t exist.
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue.

I am running the latest version of Craft.

I have replicated the issue locally and on our staging server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the URL in the browser when you click the link?

Comment: it looks like this: "/actions/users/setpassword?code=9a46516c-738c-40a7-974d-864d2d1093d6&id=ace5eb07-f6e9-461c-9f2a-df6859197b31"

Comment: Is that an actual garbled character in the URL or did it just copy/paste wrong? `0‌​`

Comment: copy and pasted: actions/users/setpassword?code=6faaa0cd-d67d-4730-b191-0e72366fd648

Comment: Maybe some .htaccess rewrite rule is dropping querystring params?

Comment: I can't see anything in the htaccess that might throw this off.  I'm using the html5 boilerplate htaccess file.  the only addition is the removal of .php from urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall the specific version/build and my search-fu is weak today, but this was a bug in Craft that should have been fixed in a semi-recent build.  Try updating to the latest and see if you still have the issue.

**Update:**

Every time we've been able to investigate this issue so far, it has been because of either .htaccess stripping querystring params behind the scenes (i.e. no `[QSA]` flag on the rewrite rule), or the equivalent in nginx-land.

Comment: I tried an update and still no luck with this issue.
Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If this is on a public box and you want to send some CP/FTP credentials over to support@buildwithcraft.com, we can further look into it and I'll update here with the results.

Comment: changing RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] fixes this.... thanks

Comment: I have the `[QSA]` flag set. But it still gives the `id` error