# Account Verification or Password Reset Error

Tags: error, nginx

**Craft 2.6**

I have a site that's been running for some time and now when trying to do a password reset or account verification error I get the following message.

[image]

I found this [stack exchange thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/account-verification-error) Where Brad Bell said:

> Every time we've been able to investigate this issue so far, it has
>   been because of either .htaccess stripping querystring params behind
>   the scenes (i.e. no [QSA] flag on the rewrite rule), or the equivalent
>   in nginx-land.

This is good, however I don't know what the **The equivalent of [QSA]** is in nginx.

Here is my nginx config file  relevant bits with sensitive stuff removed.. any tips?

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.domain.ca/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.domain.ca;
    root /home/forge/www.domain.ca/public;


    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/www.domain.ca/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }



    # Localized sites, hat tip to Johannes -- https://gist.github.com/johanneslamers/f6d2bc0d7435dca130fc

    # If you are creating a localized site as per: https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide
    # the directives here will help you handle the locale redirection so that requests will
    # be routed through the appropriate index.php wherein you set the `CRAFT_LOCALE`

    # Enable this by un-commenting it, and changing the language codes as appropriate
    # Add a new location @XXrewrites and location /XX/ block for each language that
    # you need to support

    location @enrewrites {
        rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /en/index.php?p=$1? last;
    }

    location /en/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @enrewrites;
    }

    location @frrewrites {
        rewrite ^/fr/(.*)$ /fr/index.php?p=$1? last;
    }

    location /fr/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @frrewrites;
    }

    # For WordPress bots/users
    location ~ ^/(wp-login|wp-admin|wp-config|wp-content|wp-includes|(.*)\.exe) {
        return 301 https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php;
    }

}


# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.domain.ca/after/*;
```

---

---

<del>Got a partial hacky fix working. in nginx config I changed this:</del>

```
location @enrewrites {
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /en/index.php?p=$1? last;
}

location /en/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @enrewrites;
}

location @frrewrites {
    rewrite ^/fr/(.*)$ /fr/index.php?p=$1? last;
}

location /fr/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @frrewrites;
}
```

to

```
location @enrewrites {
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /en/index.php?p=$1?$query_string last;
}

location /en/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @enrewrites;
}

location @frrewrites {
    rewrite ^/fr/(.*)$ /fr/index.php?p=$1?$query_string last;
}

location /fr/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @frrewrites;
}
```

And when I got the password reset link I had to manually remove the /en/ from the url and it works. Not perfect but at least I can reset passwords.

Not a solution but more of a temporary work around.

**UPDATE 2**

Not a fix - had to remove above code as it made all interior pages return a 404.